# Check how many children a node has

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML file in this vein:

```
<manual>
    <chapter>
        <section />
        <section />
        <section />
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <section>
            <section />
            <section />
            <section />
            <section />
            <section />
            <section />
            <section />
            <section />
            <section />
            <section />
        </section>  
        <section />
        <section />
    </chapter>
</manual>
```

While I'm processing the `<manual>` node, I want to find out if there is a `<section>` node that has more than 9 children.

My initial approach was this:

```
if test="//section[count(child::section &gt; 9)]"
```

That doesn't work because the output of count() is an integer and section[] expects a node set.
something like count(//section/section) won't work because that would count all sections, not just one set of siblings.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `//section[count(section) > 9]`, the comparison operator does not belong into the `count` function call, as you had it.

Answer (score 0):

you can  use count(./section) + count(./section/section) to find the total count of the section, below is code for knowing the position of the node and count of section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="/manual/chapter">
<xsl:if test="count(./section) + count(./section/section) > 9">
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>,<xsl:value-of select="count(./section)      + count(./section/section) "/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That gives a total count for <manual>. Useful for other applications, but I was looking for 'a node that has more than 9 children'.